# how to fix ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'upload/"filename"'?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, file-upload, multer

when I upload image to AWS S3 using multer + nodejs on my EC2 I get a path error

my app works local but not on EC2

**this is ProductController.js**

```
const product_create_post = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const parseData = JSON.parse(req.body.product_info);

    const {
      name,
      product_type,
      pet_type,
      ingredients,
      description,
    } = parseData;

    const file = req.file;

    const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(file.path);

    const id = uuidv4();
    await uploadImage(`upload/${id}`, fileStream, req.file.mimetype);

    //delete upload/imgs after uploading to s3 is complete
    await unlinkFile(file.path);

    //INSERT INTO product
    await pool.query(
      'INSERT INTO product (name, product_type_id, pet_type_id, description, img_url) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)',
      [name, product_type, pet_type, description, `upload/${id}`]
    );

    //get saved product_id
    const product_id = await pool.query(
      'SELECT id FROM product WHERE name = $1',
      [name]
    );

    // INSERT INTO ingredient if ingredient not exist in table
    const ingredientsToMap = ingredients;

    ingredientsToMap.map(async (item) => {
      await pool.query(
        'INSERT INTO ingredient (name) VALUES ($1) ON CONFLICT (name) DO NOTHING',
        [item]
      );

      //get ids from ingredient
      const ids = await pool.query(
        'SELECT id FROM ingredient WHERE name = $1',
        [item]
      );
      //INSERT INTO JUNCTION TABLE
      await pool.query(
        'INSERT INTO ingredient_product (ingredient_id, product_id) VALUES ($1, $2)',
        [ids.rows[0].id, product_id.rows[0].id]
      );
    });

    res.status(201).json('post success');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
  }
};
```

**this is ProductRoute.js**

```
const multer = require('multer');

const upload = multer({ dest: 'upload/' });

//create PRODUCT
router.post(
  '/create',
  upload.single('image'),
  productController.product_create_post
);
```

**this is my LOCAL DEV directory **

```
Server/
       Controller/
       Route/
       Upload/
       index.js
```

**this is EC2 directory**

```
drwxrwxr-x   2 ubuntu ubuntu  4096 Apr 10 04:27 controllers
-rw-rw-r--   1 ubuntu ubuntu  3325 Apr  9 14:14 database.sql
-rw-rw-r--   1 ubuntu ubuntu   270 Apr  9 14:14 db.js
-rw-rw-r--   1 ubuntu ubuntu   570 Apr  9 14:14 index.js
drwxrwxr-x 210 ubuntu ubuntu 12288 Apr 10 03:35 node_modules
-rw-rw-r--   1 ubuntu ubuntu 68172 Apr 10 03:30 package-lock.json
-rw-rw-r--   1 ubuntu ubuntu   462 Apr  9 14:14 package.json
-rw-rw-r--   1 ubuntu ubuntu     0 Apr 10 03:51 productController.js
drwxrwxr-x   2 ubuntu ubuntu  4096 Apr 10 04:19 routes
-rw-rw-r--   1 ubuntu ubuntu  1017 Apr  9 14:14 s3.js
drwxrwxr-x   2 ubuntu ubuntu  4096 Apr 10 05:08 upload
```

**this is a full error message from pm2 logs**

```
0|index  | POST /api/v1/products/create 500 40.833 ms - 223
0|index  | Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'upload/81d00e076c352c51e0239cf2a451b14a'
```

as I mentioned above same code works on my local dev environment, this is my first time deploying to EC2 so I might have missed something?

Thank you!

*Edit: I have tried using __dirname with path.join and adding '../' before file.path.. and none of them worked gave me same error msg

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `multer-s3` package. It is a package that you can combine with `multer` to upload directly to `S3`.

Here is the package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer-s3